# Custom directive does not appear in the page

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following html page

```
<input type="text" value="Doe">
<h3>Search Result</h3>
<div class="list-group">
    <search-result></search-result>
    <search-result></search-result>
</div>
```

and here is my angular directive

```
    var app=angular.module('App',['ngRoute']);
    app.config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
        .when('/',{
            templateUrl:'pages/main.html',
            controller:'mainController'
        })

    })

myApp.directive("searchResult", function() {
   return {

       template: '<a href="#" class="list-group-item"><h4 class="list-group-item-heading">Doe, John</h4><p class="list-group-item-text">555 Main St., New York, NY 11111</p></a>'
   }
});
```

The problem is, when I load the page the custom directive does not appear in my page. There is no error in console.I checked the `inspect -> Element` in the browser. It has the `<search-result></search-result>` but it seems that, it is ignored.

How can i fix it?

Comment: I think  restrict: 'AECM', should be  restrict: 'AEC',

Comment: No, i even removed the **restrict** and **replace**, but still does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this

```
myApp.directive("searchResult", function()
```

it should be

```
app.directive("searchResult", function()
```